# python list, sort list with in list

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, parsing, unique

I am pulling from an JSON API. I pull out one of the key values and then parse out all the bad characters.

```
for c in CERT.search(domain, fields=CertField):
  dn = (c['parsed.subject_dn'])
  CN = ((dn.split("CN=",1)[1]).split(' ', 1)[0]).strip(',').strip('*')
  print(CN)
```

it returns output like this &, and i need to sort and find unique values when i use set or sorted, it breaks the words into characters instead of separating the values.

```
example.com
example.com
example.com
kwejnrwkejn.example.com
kwejnrwkejn.example.com
```

I need it to only return uniquie values like
example.com
kwejnrwkejn.example.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` for storing unique items. Then `sorted()` to print sorted items. For example:

```
unique = set()  # <--- use set for storing the domains

for c in CERT.search(domain, fields=CertField):
    dn = c["parsed.subject_dn"]
    CN = ((dn.split("CN=", 1)[1]).split(" ", 1)[0]).strip(",").strip("*")

    unique.add(CN)  # <-- add domain

print(sorted(unique))  # <-- print sorted unique items
```